# Syntax error with rubygem elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems

I have a problem using the [rubygem for elasticsearch](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/)
When I try to execute the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
```

I get the following error :

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
                                       ^
```

Any ideas about this ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use Ruby prior to 1.9 version. If so, either update Ruby (which is recommended), or use old rocket-hash syntax:

```
client = Elasticsearch.new :log => true
```

Comment: You are right, I was using ruby 1.8. Upgraded to 2.1 and the problem is now fixed. Thanks for your help.